# Warning: Error in filter renderDataTable

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create Search Tool in R [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) as below code
However, it popped up with error message once run

```
Warning: Error in filter: object 'Category' not found
  [No stack trace available]
```

I am new with R shiny. Any recommendation would be greatly appreciated
Thanks heaps

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Data frame
df <- read.csv("Z:/Valuations Risk & Quality/July 2018- Commercial Panel Look up Tool - R/CSV/PanelFirmList.csv", header=TRUE)
df$Postcode<- as.character(df$Postcode)
df <- df[,c(4,3,6,9,10,11,12,13,14)]

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("NAB Panel lookup tool"),

  # Postcode textbox 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("postcode",
                "Postcode"
      ),
      selectInput("category",
                  "Category",
                  choices = unique(df$Category)
      ),
      selectInput("panel",
                  "Panel Type",
                  choices = unique(df$Panel_Type)
      ),
      selectInput("value",
                  "Value Range",
                  choices = unique(df$Value_Range)
      )
    ),
    # Show filtered data frame
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to produce table
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df %>% 
      filter ((Postcode == input$postcode) & (Category == input$category) & (Panel_Type == input$panel) & (Value_Range == input$value)) %>% 
      select(c(Region, Valifirm, Email, Phone))
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Would you mind recreating a sample version of `df` that we can use to help resolve this issue? You can read more about making minimal reproducible data sets here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: Are you sure `df` contains a column `Category`?

Comment: Did you load `dplyr`?